# Compare entries logged monthly

Tags: sql, compare, sql-server-2014

I have an SQL table that logs monthly entries.

The entries are contents of a .csv text file.

The content has multiple fields that repeat so the primary key is a compound key that includes the Name (varchar), Description (varchar), and ReportRan (datetime).
Once a file is logged it looks like:

```
 Name | Description | ReportRan
comp1 | some data   | 2017-01-01
comp1 | more data   | 2017-01-01
comp1 | even more   | 2017-01-01
comp1 | s0me data   | 2017-02-01
comp1 | more data   | 2017-02-01
comp1 | new data    | 2017-02-01
```

I need to get rows that were in January and not in February. (row3)

Rows in February that weren't in January. (row6)

And rows that had a field change between months. (row4)

Comment: PK = name + description + date?

Comment: How can you tell the difference between "rows that were in January and not in February" and "rows that had a field change between months"? If the values are different then the rows are different, by your definition of the primary key.

Comment: @McNets yes the primary key is a compound. There are more fields, but they are irrelevant and duplicate just as often.

Comment: @bbrumm the first one I want to know if the report had an entry in January, but didn't have the entry in the February report. And as for field changes you are right. If I just log any row that is different then in the next months entries then that will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS:

Rows of Month=1 that doesn't exists on Month=2

```
select t1.Name, t1.Description, t1.ReportRan
from   your_table t1
where  month(t1.ReportRan) = 1
and    not exists (select 1
                  from your_table t2
                  where t1.Name = t2.Name
                  and   t1.Description = t2.Description
                  and   month(t2.ReportRan) = 2);
```

Or rows of Month=2 that doesn't exists on Month=1

```
select t1.Name, t1.Description, t1.ReportRan
from   your_table t1
where  month(t1.ReportRan) = 2
and    not exists (select 1
                  from your_table t2
                  where t1.Name = t2.Name
                  and   t1.Description = t2.Description
                  and   month(t2.ReportRan) = 1);
```

By now, to get all rows that chaged I've used a UNION with previous queries.

```
select t1.Name, t1.Description, t1.ReportRan
from   @tbl t1
where  month(t1.ReportRan) = 1
and    not exists (select 1
                  from @tbl t2
                  where t1.Name = t2.Name
                  and   t1.Description = t2.Description
                  and   month(t2.ReportRan) = 2)
UNION
select t1.Name, t1.Description, t1.ReportRan
from   @tbl t1
where  month(t1.ReportRan) = 2
and    not exists (select 1
                  from @tbl t2
                  where t1.Name = t2.Name
                  and   t1.Description = t2.Description
                  and   month(t2.ReportRan) = 1);


|Name |Description|ReportRan          |
|:----|:----------|:------------------|
|comp1|some data  |01/01/2017 00:00:00|
|comp1|even more  |01/01/2017 00:00:00|

|Name |Description|ReportRan          |
|:----|:----------|:------------------|
|comp1|s0me data  |01/02/2017 00:00:00|
|comp1|new data   |01/02/2017 00:00:00|

|Name |Description|ReportRan          |
|:----|:----------|:------------------|
|comp1|even more  |01/01/2017 00:00:00|
|comp1|new data   |01/02/2017 00:00:00|
|comp1|s0me data  |01/02/2017 00:00:00|
|comp1|some data  |01/01/2017 00:00:00|
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e60d9055561897979691f253f7ff7b21)*

Comment: the second query was close. After looking through the text files I see the one the query caught, but it still missed another entry that was new to the February report. Does the subquery need a t1 or t2 specified for the reportran?

Comment: ReportRan is a date or a datetime field?

Comment: the first query didn't work for me at all. I found matching rows (that obviously had the different date field) and removed the February entry. ran query 1 and nothing returned. and for the third query, description were only different as an example. if name or any of the other fields are different I would need to log it. But I think @bbrumm opened my eyes to understand logging the whole row is fine since it would fall under a new row in the new month's report.

Comment: Just a date field.

Comment: I believe the second query works actually. Between me getting a little backwards and adding the non-PK fields in the where clause I got the proper returns. and I don't think we've lost any rows from the previous month so none would show up in the first query. I will remove a row to test that. but I think you have figured out that part of my problem. Any ideas for when I don't want all my fields to match?

Comment: I'll try to set up a rextester or dbfiddle sample just to check it.

Comment: would it be a full outer join by chance? when I think on the venn diagram of joins inner grabbing rows where the 'where' clause meets. does an outer grab where the 'where' clause don't meet? and if so, would my results be convoluted by rows that really shouldn't be compared like row1's description against row6's description. clearly different, but not the two rows I wanted to compare

Comment: I think a union is better http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e60d9055561897979691f253f7ff7b21, but I'm  trying to find a simple solution